# Updating HTML file using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to be able to save changes that I've made to an HTML file using BeautifulSoup. My script currently is able to locate all the hrefs in an HTML file that contain the word "data" in them, and is then able to construct a new href utilizing a url result from Google. The tag value is correctly printing but the issue is that I am unable to see those changes reflected in the output file as it does not seem that the Soup is being updated.

Updated to reflect working solution -

```
# making the soup
htmlDoc = open('test.html', "r+")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlDoc)

i = 0 #initialize counter

for tag in soup.findAll(href=re.compile("data")): #match for href's with keyword data
    i += 1
    print i
    print tag.get_text()    
    text = tag.get_text() + "applications"
    g = pygoogle(text)
    g.pages = 1
    # print '*Found %s results*'%(g.get_result_count())
    if "http" in g.get_first_url(): 
        print g.get_first_url()
        new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href=g.get_first_url())
        new_tag.string = tag.get_text()
        print new_tag
        tag.replace_with(new_tag)


print "Remaining"
print i

htmlDoc.close()

html = soup.prettify(soup.original_encoding)
with open("test.html", "wb") as file:
    file.write(html)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have created a new tag `new_tag = soup.new_tag("a", href=g.get_first_url())`, but you haven't actually inserted `new_tag` into the `HTML` code, you have only assigned it to a variable `new_tag`.

you need to use either the `insert()` or `append()` method supplied by [BeatifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), for the tag to actually be placed in the html.

Or you can reassign the `'href'` of the link, using the following:

```
htmlDoc = open('test.html', "r+")
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlDoc)

i = 0 #initialize counter

for tag in soup.findAll(href=re.compile("data")): #match for href's with keyword data
    i += 1
    print i
    print tag.get_text()    
    text = tag.get_text() + "applications"
    g = pygoogle(text)
    g.pages = 1
    # print '*Found %s results*'%(g.get_result_count())
    if "http" in g.get_first_url(): 
        print g.get_first_url()
        new_tag['href'] = g.get_first_url()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, realized I should have been using replace_with(), and that I ought to be working with the same input file for output too. Modified code to show what I was seeking.